# how to store downloaded image in internal storage using Download Manager in android

Tags: android

how to save image or mp3 file in internal storage using Download manager

Code:

```
   public void StartDownload(String path)
   {
   ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
        File directory = cw.getDir("channel" + cId, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdir();
        }
        DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

        Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(path);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                downloadUri);
        String imgnm = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        startdownloadurl = directory.getAbsolutePath()+"/";
        System.out.println(" directory " + startdownloadurl);
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
                DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle(imgnm)
                .setDescription("Downloading...")
                .setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true)
                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(startdownloadurl, imgnm);


        mgr.enqueue(request);
    }
```

i  m trying to store downloaded image or mp3 file in my internal storage 
but it not work well
required path is "data/data/packagename/app_channel1/image1.jpg"

Comment: whats your logcat are saying?

Comment: image download perfactly and it save in sdcard, and i can easily open that image but i want to save that image in my app package and downloaded image can only this app

Comment: File directory = cw.getDir("channel" + cId, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); that's why only your app can open image

Comment: but it not work well, i can open that image in my device also